# Third Fragment is not loading in tabbed activity and getting Error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

Basically I have three fragments in viewpager creating a tabbed activity. I have a button "GotoCart" in my Main activity named as "SecondActivity".The working of that button is that when it is clicked it moves to a new Activity named as "Cart". In cart I have an ListView which is getting its data from three different ArrayList individually exists in each Fragment.Now the issue is that when I clicked on "GoToCart" button first Two fragments ArrayLists gets initialized and putt their data in FinalList but it shows error for [Screen Shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkn0j.png) third fragment that the "arrayList is not initialized".Working for first two fragments but not for third i don't understand what's the issue is. Please Help!!!. Following is the third fragment .java file.

```
public class FragSandwitch extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,Serializable{
Button btnadd1,btnadd2,btnadd3,btnadd4,btnadd5;
static ArrayList<SingleCartItem> sandwichList;
String x,y;
TextView itemName,price;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_sandwich, container, false);
    btnadd1=(Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich1_btn_add);
    btnadd2=(Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich2_btn_add);
    btnadd3=(Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich3_btn_add);
    btnadd4=(Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich4_btn_add);
    btnadd5=(Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich5_btn_add);

    sandwichList = new ArrayList<SingleCartItem>();

    btnadd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(btnadd1.getText().toString().equals("+ADD")) {
                itemName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich1_txt_name);
                price = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich1_txt_price);
                x = (String) itemName.getText();
                y = (String) price.getText();
                sandwichList.add(new SingleCartItem(x, y));
                btnadd1.setText("Added to Cart");
            }
        }
    });
    btnadd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btnadd2.getText().toString().equals("+ADD")) {
                itemName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich2_txt_name);
                price = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich2_txt_price);
                x = (String) itemName.getText();
                y = (String) price.getText();
                sandwichList.add(new SingleCartItem(x, y));
                btnadd2.setText("Added to Cart");
            }

        }

    });
    btnadd3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btnadd3.getText().toString().equals("+ADD")) {
                itemName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich3_txt_name);
                price = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich3_txt_price);
                x = (String) itemName.getText();
                y = (String) price.getText();
                sandwichList.add(new SingleCartItem(x, y));
                btnadd3.setText("Added to Cart");
            }
        }

    });
    btnadd4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btnadd4.getText().toString().equals("+ADD")){
                itemName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich4_txt_name);
                price = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich4_txt_price);
                x = (String) itemName.getText();
                y = (String) price.getText();
                sandwichList.add(new SingleCartItem(x, y));
                btnadd4.setText("Added to Cart");
            }
        }

    });
    btnadd5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(btnadd5.getText().toString().equals("+ADD")){
                itemName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich5_txt_name);
                price = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.sandwich5_txt_price);
                x=(String)itemName.getText();
                y=(String)price.getText();
                sandwichList.add(new SingleCartItem(x,y));
                btnadd5.setText("Added to Cart");
            }
        }
    });
    return myView;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

this is the "SecondActivity" Code for "onClick" of "GoToCart" button.

```
public void goToCart(View view) {


    for (int i=0;i<FragBurger.burgerList.size();i++)//working
        finalList.add(FragBurger.burgerList.get(i));

    for (int i=0;i<FragPizza.pizzaList.size();i++)//working
        finalList.add(FragPizza.pizzaList.get(i));

    for (int i=0;i<FragSandwitch.sandwichList.size();i++)//Error
        finalList.add(FragSandwitch.sandwichList.get(i));
    Intent goToCart=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,Cart.class);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)finalList);
    goToCart.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
    startActivity(goToCart);
}
```

"Cart" Activity:

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

ArrayList<SingleCartItem> arrayList;
ListView listView;
TextView quantity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cart);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Cart");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.added_list_items);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    arrayList = (ArrayList<SingleCartItem>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
    MyAdapterView my_adapter_view=new MyAdapterView( getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
    my_adapter_view.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setAdapter(my_adapter_view);
    args.remove("BUNDLE");}}
```